# "1 new answer has been added" is not removed if answer is deleted

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, live-refresh

If a question page is open and an answer is posted, a bar saying for example "1 new answer has been added" appears.

However, it remains if the answer is deleted.

**The bar should be updated and/or removed if the answer that triggered the display of it is deleted,** to reduce the risk of confusion. (I know what this is about, but a new user might not and would probably be confused if the site says that an answer has been added and then when they reload it's not there.)